# sharing a graph story with UIImage using Facebook sdk

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to generate a story object and post it to facebook using facebook share dialog.
it works well with only one issue:

**i'm trying to use an UIImage instead of image url.**

when the share dialog is opened, i can see the image selected by the user.
after posting, i can see on facebook.com site an image from my site.com instead of the UIImage i sent.

Any ideas ?

```
 NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *object =
    [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"name_app:artwork"
                                            title:@"User generated content"
                                            image:self.artworkImage
                                              url:self.myAppWebSiteUrl
                                      description:@""];;

    id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
    action[@"artwork"] = object;


    if ( [FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithOpenGraphActionParams:action]) {
        [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:action
                                              actionType:@"name_app:contribute"
                                     previewPropertyName:@"artwork"
                                                 handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                     [self close];
                                                     if(error) {
                                                         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                                     } else {
                                                         NSLog(@"Success");
                                                     }
                                                 }];

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `self.artworkImage` associated to the object's `image` parameter is used as a thumbnail to the `url`. If I understood correctly you want to send the `UIImage` as a part of the story - in that case you should assign your UIImage to the action's `image` object. Check this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/open-graph#image) for how to append local images to your story.

Let me know if it helped you.